# UnsatisfiedLinkError for a basic native method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have those two super basic methods in Java like so:

```
package com.lisek;

class HelloWorldJNI {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorldJNI helloWorldJNI = new HelloWorldJNI();
        helloWorldJNI.sayHello();
        helloWorldJNI.sayHello2();
    }

    // Declare a native method sayHello() that receives no arguments and returns void
    private native void sayHello();
    private native void sayHello2();
}
```

I am generating JNI files like so `javac -h . HelloWorldJNI.java` which results in such `com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.h` file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI */

#ifndef _Included_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI
#define _Included_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI
 * Method:    sayHello2
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello2
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And I am doing implementation of those in the same exact manner in the `com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.cpp` file like so:

```
#include "com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {
   std::cout << "Hello from C++ !!" << std::endl;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello2 (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {
    std::cout << "Hello from C++ !!" << std::endl;
}
```

I am compiling the code with `g++ -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\include\win32" com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.o` and generating `.dll` with `g++ -shared -o native.dll com_lisek_HelloWorldJNI.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias`. All looks very well to me and I can not spot any flaw of this code but nevertheless in Java while running the code I am getting exception only on the second method:

```
Hello from C++ !!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.lisek.HelloWorldJNI.sayHello2()V
    at com.lisek.HelloWorldJNI.sayHello2(Native Method)
    at com.lisek.HelloWorldJNI.main(HelloWorldJNI.java:12)
```

It means to me that the .dll is loaded properly as if I do two calls of the `sayHello()` I will get the `Hello` twice. Seriously, what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to compile and run your code with `-Djava.library.path` flag set like so:

`java -cp . -Djava.library.path="D:\\Workspace\\JNI\\Callback\\src\\com\\lisek" com.lisek.HelloWorldJNI`

But it still dazzles me that it was able to run the first `sayHello()` but was not able to run `sayHello2()`. Can't think of any reasonable idea why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing example from https://www.baeldung.com/jni then make sure that you add these includes into cpp file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Main.h"
```